How to properly use MermaidJS in Angular?
I was going to use mermaid in Angular by installing the module with npm i -D mermaid and test with one of the examples of the docs, ok but it does not work. Seems like a frequent problem.
I tried the following code with and without calling the JS API through .
<pre class="mermaid">
    graph TD
    A[Client] --> B[Load Balancer]
    B --> C[Server01]
    B --> D[Server02]

    journey
    title My working day
    section Go to work
      Make tea: 5: Me
      Go upstairs: 3: Me
      Do work: 1: Me, Cat
    section Go home
      Go downstairs: 5: Me
      Sit down: 5: Me
</pre>

<script type="module">
  import mermaid from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mermaid@10/dist/mermaid.esm.min.mjs';
  mermaid.initialize({ startOnLoad: true });
</script>

output
I tried using this solution but it doesnt work too. (Property 'mermaid' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor & Property 'initialize' does not exist on type 'typeof ).
Thanks.

Can you share the code where you initialize mermaid lib?

Updated. Just like the docs, and i tried above and beneath the code.

Hmmm when building, Angular will parse the template, grab the <script> tag and process it as part of the bundle. So it will be moved as if it was in the component file. Issue with that is that at that point there's nothing to initialize because template hasn't been rendered yet. Have you tried installing the dependency via NPM, importing as usual (like the post you mentioned) and then call initialize in afterContentInit lifecycle hook? However that's only for browser so maybe using afterNextRender instead

@davidlj95 I didnt understand what you mean by calling initialize, even having searched for such function. Where can i understand more about that thing Angular does to 
Just added an answer of how I'd initialize mermaid in a project. About Angular & <script> tag behaviour: https://angular.dev/guide/templates#empower-your-html

The modern but in developer preview way
You can import the library and initialize it after Angular has finished rendering the template in the browser. To do so, you can use the afterNextRender API. Beware that the API is still in developer preview, so it's not stable yet
import { afterNextRender, Component } from "@angular/core";
import mermaid from "mermaid";

@Component({
 // ...
})
export class MermaidComponent {
  constructor() {
    afterNextRender({
      read: () => {
        void mermaid.init()
      }
    })
  }
}


The void before mermaid.init can actually be removed. It's just to ignore the linter warning about not waiting for .init promise

This way Angular will wait until the template is there so Mermaid can be initialized when HTML elements are there.
By using this API, the initialization code only runs on the browser. Which is useful as mermaid doesn't support server side rendering (yet?)
Stable way
If you want to use something stable to check if the app is running in a browser or not to perform the initialization, you can also use:

PLATFORM_ID and isPlatformBrowser APIs to ensure the init code runs only on the browser
AfterViewInit lifecycle callback to ensure the HTML elements are there when initializing

import { AfterViewInit, Component, Inject, PLATFORM_ID } from "@angular/core";
import { isPlatformBrowser } from "@angular/common";
import mermaid from "mermaid";

@Component({
  // ...
})
export class MermaidComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  constructor(@Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private _platformId: object) {
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    if (isPlatformBrowser(this._platformId)) {
      void mermaid.init()
    }
  }
}


If you're sure you won't ever run your app with server side rendering (SSR) or pre-rendering (SSG) you could actually skip the if clause regarding where the code runs on the browser. But just in case it's a good practice to think about it just in case you want to add that later to your project

Example app
Created also an example Angular v18 app using mermaid in case you want to take a look. The important piece is the MermaidComponent.
The second alternative code is in the classic-way branch
